# Searching user input string in excel sheet and find the string respective cell information and display range of column from the sheet

Tags: python

In a python script, I need to search for the user input string in an excel sheet,  find the string , then display the respective row/column details of the cell where the user input was found.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: i need to write the python scripts to get the details and search in the xls sheet and display the column (range (1:10) details. 

need details

Answer (score 0):

use argparser to get the input from the cmd
and use the xlrd to read the excel sheet